# CSRF protection on AJAX authentication in Flask

Tags: python, ajax, flask, csrf

I'd like to AJAXify both a login and a signup form on a site. Up to now I've been using WTForms mainly for its built-in CSRF protetion, but for this project I didn't feel like it was worth it -- an extra layer of abstraction, and therefore frustration, for something that should be pretty simple.

So I came across [this snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/3/) on Flask's security section:

```
@app.before_request
def csrf_protect():
    if request.method == "POST":
        token = session.pop('_csrf_token', None)
        if not token or token != request.form.get('_csrf_token'):
        abort(403)

def generate_csrf_token():
    if '_csrf_token' not in session:
        session['_csrf_token'] = some_random_string()
    return session['_csrf_token']

app.jinja_env.globals['csrf_token'] = generate_csrf_token
```

I understand the thought process behind this code. In fact, it all makes perfect sense to me (I think). I can't see anything wrong with it.

But it doesn't work. The only thing I've changed about the code is replacing the pseudofunction `some_random_string()` with a call to `os.urandom(24)`. Every request has 403'd so far because `token` and `request.form.get('_csrf_token')` are never the same. When I print them this becomes obvious -- usually they're different strings, but occasionally, and seemingly with no underlying reason, one or the other will be `None` or a truncated version of the output of `os.urandom(24)`. Obviously something out of sync, but I'm not understanding what it is.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the convenience of `flask-wtf` without all the heaviness, and without rolling your own:

```
from flask_wtf.csrf import CsrfProtect
```

then on init, either:

```
CsrfProtect(app)
```

or:

```
csrf = CsrfProtect()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    csrf.init_app(app)
```

The token will then be available app-wide at any point, including via `jinja2`:

```
<form method="post" action="/">
  <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
</form>
```

(via the [docs](http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/csrf.html))

Comment: Please note that: "FlaskWTFDeprecationWarning: "flask_wtf.CsrfProtect" has been renamed to "CSRFProtect" and will be removed in 1.0."

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is os.urandom function. The result of this function can contains symbols which not will parse properly in html. So when you insert csrf_token in html and don't do any escaping, you have the described problem.

**How to fix.**
Try to escape csrf_token in html [(see docs)](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#html-escaping) or use another approach for generating csrf token. For example using uuid:

```
import uuid
...

def generate_random_string():
    return str(uuid.uuid4())
...
```

Comment: I suppose I should have mentioned that I base64 encoded the output of urandom(). Apparently that wasn't the right solution though. I'll check with your solution as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: I gave you an upvote for the effort, but unfortunately the problem remains. The call to `generate_csrf_token()` in the template works fine (and `reqest.form.get('_csrf_token')` is accessing the token properly), but it's not in the session for some reason. It prints as `None`, which I don't understand at all, because `app.jinja_env.globals['csrf_token']` uses it. Somewhere between the call to `generate_csrf_token()` and `csrf_protect()` it disappears from the session and returns `None` according to `session.pop('_csrf_token', None)`. But it was just used!

Comment: Can you give session configuration?

Comment: I actually solved the problem eventually, and the answer is embarrassing. When I first started the project I installed both WTForms and flask-wtf (largely out of habit) before deciding to abandon them. After stripping out enormous portions of my code I realized it was their built-in CSRF protection that was interfering with what I was trying to do. I do appreciate the time you took to help me, though.